# Workbench install 64-bit on Windows 7

Tags: workbench

I have downloaded the Workbench 2.0.0 zip file and followed the install new software -> add -> archive steps to install the workbench plugin. After that, the Workbench core and webMathematica tools are listed as already installed. 
I installed the plugin into a 3.8 vintage eclipse.

When I try to "Run" a notebook in a *Mathematica* projects (basic or application) I get the following error message:

> FrontEnd Job:: Open Notebook has enountered a problem. An internal error occurred during::FrontEnd Job::Open Notebook.
>
> Details: an internal error occurred during: "FrontEnd Job::Open Notebook".
>   com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.MLOpenString(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)J

I believe I have the right path to the *Mathematica* executable (when I change the path to point to a non existing file, I get a message that says to adjust the path).

Most postings on this site suggest that 32-bit is the only workable solution while at least one post indicated that there is a workaround for 64-bit machines.

I'd rather use 64-bit kepler (4.2 vintage eclipse).  Is that possible?

I couldn't find the details from the one posting that indicated 64-bit is possible. Can someone provide the details?

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you trying to run? I've had some troubles with 6.0.1 and Workbench, because 6.0.1 doesn't fully support 64-bit JVM's afaik. That was on a Mac though, so I'm not sure how relevant it is for your case.

Comment: @teakeNutma  I am using Mathematica 9.0.1.0.

Comment: I have this problem sometimes, for example today, windows 8.1 x64@Mathematica 10.0 workbench2

Comment: I have the same problem too. Can someone help?

Comment: @Kuba, I've already written them but they did not provide an answer. Instead WRI support provided access to the new Workbench 3.0 which gives the same exact error..

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66781/workbench-installation-issue-on-windows-8-1?rq=1

Comment: @iav Thanks, well that is unfortunate, hope you will find the solution.

Comment: @ilian this fix doesn't work for me :/ and I don't have V9 to try iav's solution. Is there any way around it?

Comment: @Kuba I am pretty sure that workaround is obsolete by now, maybe I should just delete it. My general advice would be to avoid Workbench, but instead use Eclipse Neon with the latest version of the plugin (ask support for it).

Comment: @ilian will in work on x64  Neon?\

Comment: @Kuba Sure, I've been using it with 64-bit Eclipse (on Mac and Windows at least).

Comment: @ilian thanks, petition sent. If that is the only stable way maybe you could post an answer.

Comment: @ilian Actually you could push for a general release of a new Eclipse plugin, please. I got an old plugin (3.0.113) from support once, but this one does not work with Eclipse Neon. And I am scheduled to give a Workbench course [here](http://www.ugent.be/doctoralschools/en/doctoraltraining/courses/specialistcourses/bse/mathematica-2016.htm) in November, and I already told the organizer I will not go if there is no new version of Workbench and the plugin. I find it amazing how WRI is treating its users, i.e., still offering no real IDE (the normal FrontEnd does not count).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem in the following way.

1. Uninstall Mathematica 10 and Workbench.
2. Install Mathematica 9
3. Install Workbench
4. Test whether everything works (it worked for me at this stage)
5. Install Mathematica 10
6. Change the paths in Preferences\Mathematica to Mathematica 10

This should be it.